# Something about the group of translations of vector space.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $\mathrm{V} = \mathrm{V(n, q)}$ be the vector space of dimension n over the field $\mathbb{F}_q$.

$T = \{ \sigma_v: x \mapsto x + v \mid v \in \mathrm{V} \}$ is the group of translations of $\mathrm{V}$.

$\mathrm{AGL(V)}$ is the general affine group of $\mathrm{V}$.

$S_{\mathrm{V}}$ is the symmetric group of $\mathrm{V}$.

I am interested in the set
$$ H = \{ g \in S_{\mathrm{V}} \mid T^g < \mathrm{AGL(V)} \},$$
where group $T^g$ is conjugated of $T$ by $g$.

It is clear that $\mathrm{AGL(V)} \subset H$ and for all $\phi, \psi \in \mathrm{AGL(V)}, h \in H$
$$ \psi h \phi \in H.$$

But what else one can deduce about the elements of $H$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @verret The problem is that $H$ is not generally a subgroup of $S_V$. I just did a computer calculation with $V(3,2)$, and we have $|{\rm AGL}(V)|=1344$ and $|H| = 8|{\rm AGL}(V)|=10752$. This is because there are $8$ distinct conjugates of $T$ that are contained in ${\rm AGL}(V)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, yes, it is. And moreover the order of  $\mathrm{AGL(V)}$ always devides the order of $H$ because $H$ consists of the cosets of $\mathrm{AGL(V)}$.

Comment: I think your question is similar (and possibly equivalent)  to asking for the regular subgroups of the affine group. There is some literature on this - see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379516301306) for example.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the close votes.

Comment: @DerekHolt, thank you.